# Angular and A/B testing

Tags: angular, ab-testing

I need to add A/B testing functionality to a large application built with Angular 2 and bundled with Webpack.

Tools like VWO are not flexible enough for us.

Any online guides or tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: I figured this question might be too generic and thus misunderstood. I searched all day for resources about A/B testing with Angular 2 of Webpack with no luck, so I thought it would be good to have a thread about it here.

Answer (score -2):

In case anyone else comes with the same question, I'm launching a product to solve this need. It works great with Angular2/4 or any other JavaScript framework.

Here's an example from the [docs](https://engaugeab.com/docs/get-started/). You can easily switch out the jQuery DOM manipulation for a function that updates a variable bound to an `ng-if` for use with Angular.

```
var experiment = engauge.experiment({
    name: 'signup-button',
    variants: {
        // This is the first variant. It should be your control.
        '#ff5722': {
            activate: function() {
                $('#signup-col').html('<button class="variant-1 signup-button">Try it Free</button>');
            }
        },
        // This is the second variant. 
        '#9c27b0': {
            activate: function() {
                $('#signup-col').html('<button class="variant-2 signup-button">Try it Free</button>');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The home page is now up at https://engaugeab.com and if you mention this post i'll give you access to an extended free tier.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I updated the post to include a specific example.

Comment: i found these other options: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ab-test-service, https://www.npmjs.com/package/ab-testing,  https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ab